# OOP - pass one object to several others?

Tags: oop

I am not quite sure if this question belongs here or to another community on stackexchange, if the latter, I could not find the right one and would be glad about a hint.

I am at the moment programming a little game (roundbased -no threading) in Java and I am wondering: 
Is it bad practice if one object is known to several others?

In my case I wonder if I should create an Object o and then pass it as a constructor argument to several other, later created objects.

It does work, but I wonder if this should in general rather not be done?

Does someone have an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course. It is normal case in the world of oop. One of simple examples of such usage is dependency injection. For more information see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Besides, many design patterns use such approach : strategy, observer etc.